# ClassCastException with listviews in JavaFX when changing items' type

Tags: java, listview, javafx, classcastexception

I´m working on the presentation layer of an application, and am encountering some problems with JavaFX's "listview".

In the application's GUI, I intend to use one single listview element to alternatively (never simultaneously) display lists of two distinct objects: objects of type "Group" and objects of type "Expenditure".

When the user wants to look at the list of all groups, the following function (simplified here) is called:

```
 private void loadGroups(){

     List<Group> groups = getGroups();
     ObservableList<Group> ol = FXCollections.observableList( (List<Group>)groups );
     myListView.setCellFactory( new Callback<ListView<Group>, ListCell<Group>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Group> call(ListView<Group> listView) {
            return new GroupCell();
        }
     });
     myListView.setItems(ol);
     myListView.setOnMouseClicked(...);

 }
```

When a group is double clicked, the following code is executed, with the purpose of now displaying all Expenditure objects related to that group on the same ListView:

```
 private void loadGroups(){

     List<Expenditure> expenditures = getExpenditures();
     ObservableList<Expenditure> ol = FXCollections.observableList( (List<Expenditure>)expenditures );
     myListView.setCellFactory( new Callback<ListView<Expenditure>, ListCell<Expenditure>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Expenditure> call(ListView<Expenditure> listView) {
            System.out.println("updateView() called for expenditures.................");
            return new ExpenditureCell();
        }
     });
     myListView.setItems(ol);
     myListView.setOnMouseClicked(...);

 }
```

The GroupCell and ExpenditureCell  objects override the updateItem methods according to the following pattern (I will just show the overriden method for the GroupCell object):

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Group group, boolean empty) {

    super.updateItem(group, empty);

    if (empty){
        setGraphic(null);
    }else{
        GroupCellController groupCellController = new GroupCellController();
        groupCellController.setGroupInfo(group);
        setGraphic(groupCellController.getAnchorPane());
        //addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, eve);
    }

}
```

If the user first looks at the list of groups and then decides to look at the list of expenditures, the following error happens:

```
  Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: DATA.Model.Expenditure cannot be cast to DATA.Model.Group
```

I´m at a loss here. The CellFactories are being correctly replaced, and so are the observable lists.

Answer (score 3):

How are you declaring `myListView`?

I think the problem is that when you replace the cell factory, it immediately tries to display the current items, which of course are the wrong type. If you really want to do things this way, try

```
myListView.getItems().clear();
```

before changing the cell factory.

All of this just looks like a big hack though. A `ListView` is typed and you are supposed to use it as such. You really can't change its type at runtime. Is there any reason not to simply switch to a different `ListView` (i.e. switch between a `ListView<Group>` and a `ListView<Expenditure>`, instead of just reconfiguring a single `ListView<???>`)?

Comment: myListView is linked to a tag in an fxml file that describes the whole scene. The code is the following: 
    "@FXML
    ListView myListView;"

I understand your point about using one listview for each object. However, in terms of visuals I´d like those two lists to occupy the same space in the app's window. What strategies could I use to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: @ismarlowe It's basically a mistake to use raw types for generic classes unless you're doing so for back compatibility reasons. You can create two list views in the FXML file, put them in a stack pane, and toggle their visibility, for example.